Dynamic Allocation or Declaration of Robot Framework Variables
I have a script that automatically generates Robot Framework testcases based on a few parameters. Now in this generated testcases there might a ssh connection or some other things that has predefined values and were used in multiple places.
For reference,
*** Test Case ***

Verify Same Value Usage Without Variables
    Log    Hello World
    Should Be Equal    Hello World    Hello World
    Comment    This test repeats "Hello World" without using variables
    Log    Hello World
    Should Contain    Hello World    World


I want this values to be allocated using a variable name and replace the value with the variable throughout the test suite and make this like:
*** Variables ***
${MESSAGE}    Hello World

*** Test Case ***
Verify Same Value Usage With Variable
    Log    ${MESSAGE}
    Should Be Equal    ${MESSAGE}    ${MESSAGE}
    Comment    This test uses the variable ${MESSAGE}
    Log    ${MESSAGE}
    Should Contain    ${MESSAGE}    World


Is that possible through a script?
I have found no solution for this yet. Any ideas will be more than welcome!

Answer is "Yes, it can be done".  But since you do not share any details about how your script generates your robot stuff or what sort of data is used for the script, nobody can't really answer you.

On the most simple case, you could use test templates and just feed the variables as arguments to the template or by using datadriver. See https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/testcase_styles/datadriven

@rasjani The script generates a Robot Framework file based on how a device is configured. For instance, when a few RPCs are sent to a device, they are recorded, parsed, and used as a basis to generate test cases automatically.

point of statement was  "i dont see any code, no idea how to modify it".
